# Yahoo Fantasy App styled buttons

Tags: android, button, android-activity

I'm trying to accomplish the style of buttons used in the yahoo fantasy football app. On the nav bar located at the bottom of the screen there are buttons. Now I've extracted the assets from the app so I know that the magnifying glass is of course an image, but there are two. A blue one and a grey one. However the button "underlay" which is transparent doesn't appear to be an image.

Example: https://i.stack.imgur.com/ASNzz.jpg

I want to replicate this type of button, with the following characteristics.

1. A gradient background (I know how to do this, but I want to be clear that #2 needs to be able to reflect a background that isn't a solid color)
2. A "button underlay" that is transparent with rounded corners, like the example.
3. Changing icons (magnifying glass)
4. And then of course, it being a button. More specifically launching another activity in my app.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think that Yahoo has copied the iPhone TabBar style for that app, but it's a simple TabHost interface (here's the [tutorial](http://developer.android.com/resources/tutorials/views/hello-tabwidget.html))

On the internet you can find many XML examples for the TabBar style, I suggest these ones (that in my opinion are the best)

- https://github.com/AdilSoomro/Iphone-Tab-in-Android : the graphical best one IMHO
- https://github.com/honcheng/ScrollableTabHost-for-Android : in this one the TabBar is horizonally scollable
- http://www.anddev.org/code-snippets-for-android-f33/iphone-tabs-for-android-t14678.html : a very easy one to implement

But I have a thing to ask you: is for your application necessary to copy the iPhone style? I leave here the link to Londatiga's [QuickActions](http://www.londatiga.net/it/how-to-create-quickaction-dialog-in-android/) which are the same style as the contacts app, twitter app, gallery app, and many many more - and it's a recommended style by the Google's engineers. It's more "androidish" ;)

Comment: It's just the style I'm going for. The whole app is sleek? I guess and the android tabs looks, more...eh techy rather than shiny. As for the quickactions. I'm styling a menu, I not really looking for any pop-up options.

Comment: Ok, so try using the first link I posted in my answer - it should fit your needs.